# Amazon Product API Search Unavailable Items

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Currently, I am using `amazonproduct` to search items' UPC code based on keywords. It worked for most of the cases. However, sometimes I did find that my current search function could not find items which were not available (or sometimes it only returned a fraction of items containing the key words). I checked the official document on the [parameter Availability](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AvailabilityParameter.html), but still not sure what is the proper value to feed to it in order to retrieve both current available and unavailable items.

For example, below code could not find `Neutrogena Moisture Rich Sunless Tanning`, which was no longer on available. However, item's information is still available [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000EP8170).

```
import amazonproduct
config = {
    'access_key': 'access_key',
    'secret_key': 'secret_key',
    'associate_tag': 'associate_tag',
    'locale': 'us'
}
api = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config)
items=api.item_search('All', Keywords=self.product_name, ResponseGroup='Medium', Availability="PROPER VALUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

The only valid value for Availability is "Available"
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ReturningPriceAndAvailabilityInformation-itemsearch.html